Extract 10 Digits starting with a 9 in excel
I am trying to solve an issue in excel in which I have a column of data that contains a mix of both letters and numbers. In a new column I would like to extract if and only if the data column contains a cell that has a 10 digit number that starts with a 9 and if not returns blank.
In the data column there can be numbers greater than 10 digits and they can appear at the beginning, end or not at all in the string. For example, 5389456287521 so while there is a 9 in this data set I would want the output to be blank because the number does not start with 9. There can be a mix of numbers and letters in the data. For example, DGTY 19523874200 which should populate as blank since it does not start with a 9. If for example the data was DGTY 9523874200 it should out with 9523874200.
Thank you
Used a number of different formulas

Can you show some data and expected output including the formula you have tried. You may be close to a solution.

=IF(AND(LEN(A1)=10,LEFT(A1,1)="9",ISNUMBER(A1)),A1,"") returns 10 digit numbers, but if not then empty string. Formula cannot return real Blank

So, "DGTY 19523874200" should return a blank (number starts with a 1), and "DGTY 9523874200" should return "9523874200" (because the number starts with a 9).  However, what should the expected outputs be for either "DGTY 95238742001" (number starts with a 9, but is 11 digits: should it be blank, or just the first 10 digits?) or "DGTY9523874200" (the number portion is 10 digits and starts with a 9, but the full word is 14 characters and starts with a D)?

Also, is there always at most one valid number?  (i.e. you can't have "ABC 9876543210 9638520741"?)

My suggestion would be
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("9?????????",A1),10)),"")

However, this formula has a flaw, as it will only consider the first occurrence of 9 in a string. For example, it will work for a1234567s91234567892, but it will fail for a1934567s91234567892.
If you need to handle both of the above cases, you would require a VBA function—at least, that's the best solution I can think of.
It also does not consider cases where you want to extract only numbers that are exactly ten digits long.
If you only need to handle cases where a cell contains exactly a 10-digit number starting with a 9, the formula mentioned in the comments by Black Cat will work.
Update 1: Based on the comments the following formula might be helpful
=LET(pos,SEARCH(""9????????"",A1),num,LEFT(A1,10),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(num*1),LEFT(A1,1)="9",LEN(num*1)=10),num,""))

This only considers cells that start with a 9 at the beginning. In order to avoid #VALUE just use IFERROR like
=IFERROR(LET(pos,SEARCH(""9????????"",A1),num,LEFT(A1,10),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(num*1),LEFT(A1,1)="9",LEN(num*1)=10),num,"")),"")

Update 2: The following formula would cover the case the 9 is somewhere in the cell
=LET(pos,SEARCH("9????????",A1),num,MID(A1,pos,10),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(num*1),LEN(num*1)=10),num,""))


Thanks so much for the reply. It got me close. I found one error in this approach. Column says 92560034  IL PinDrive reclass 1 and the output of the formula gave me 92560034 because it looks like its counting the spaces as part of the 10 character count.

One other issue I found is that for 1900000098  ABOUBHZD HON the output was 900000098 but this should have been ignored because there is a leading 1.

Yes, both of your comments are correct. Regarding the first comment, you would need to include a LEN check after converting VALUE to ensure the result remains ten digits long; otherwise, VALUE will ignore the blank spaces. As for the second comment, it depends on your specific requirements. While the formula appears to be correct, it seems your needs might differ. As mentioned in one of the earlier comments, providing sample data along with the expected output would be helpful.

Is there an opportunity to include a LEN in the existing formula =IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("9?????????",A1),10)),"") to only output the result if it is 10 characters long?

Yes, certainly. However, it would be much easier if you specified, for instance, whether the number always appears at the beginning. Even better, consider editing your original post to include this information, as not everyone reads through all the comments. Additionally, please provide some example data.

Here are some examples of the output being incorrect with the formula as is =IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("9?????????",A1),10)),"")                                                       Data: 1900000099  ABZSDAOUD HON
Incorrect Output: 900000099                                                                                              Data: ALD-Coioptible- Fra# 240159174000526
Incorrect Output: 9174000526                                                                                           Would like both of these to output "blank" since the number does not start with 9

Please update your original post accordingly. It would also be great if you could answer my question.

Updated thank you

I also updated my post but I the updated formula will not cover the case DGTY 9523874200 You would need to adjust the formula a bit.

I added a second update

Thank you, your second update got me, very close, I found one scenario where it is not provididing the correct output.                                                                                              Example: AYVGDS-Renting- Fra# 240901152005284 where its giving me output of 901152005284 but should return blank or #VALUE since it does not start with 9

If you are lucky enough to have regextest, then
=REGEXTEST(A1,"^9\d{9}$")

Or if you are looking to extract matches that are preceded by beginning of string or a non-digit,
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?:^|\D)(9\d{9})",2),"")

If you want to also check that it's followed by a non-digit or end of line:
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?:^|\D)(9\d{9}(?:$|\D))",2),"")



No, because 9 is anchored to the beginning of the string and the 9 digits anchored to the end.

This is not too sophisticated, checks conditions individually by line:
=LET(first,MATCH(TRUE,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="9",0),
val,IFERROR(VALUE((MID(A1,first,10))),""),
vala,IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,first+10,1)),""),
valb,IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,first-1,1)),""),
valc,LEN(TRIM(val))=10,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(val),NOT(ISNUMBER(vala)),NOT(ISNUMBER(valb)),valc),MID(A1,first,10),""))


Wow this seemed to do the trick. No longer seeing any issues in the output I'm expecting. Thank you very much!

Final question - I've done this formula to multiple columns and pulled out all 10 digits starting with 9 into 3 columns next to each other. I want a fourth column to look into each of the 3 columns and pull in the number if it exists in any one of the 3 columns. For example                                                                                                      Column 1: 9568785652 Column 2: blank Column 3: blank and I want the output in column 4 to show 9568785652

Workarounds:  1.)MAX(VALUE(IF(B1:D1="",0,B1:D1)))  2.) =MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(B1:D1),0))

If you have Office 365 (i.e. you can use the REDUCE and LAMBDA functions, added to Excel in December 2020), then this should work:
=REDUCE("", TEXTSPLIT(A1, " "), LAMBDA(a, v, IF(a="", IF(AND(LEN(v)=10, LEFT(v, 1)="9"), "" & IFERROR(--v, ""), a))))

This will take the input text, break it into space-separated values, and then run through each value until it finds one that is:

10 characters long (LEN(v)=10)
Starts with a "9" (LEFT(v, 1)="9")
Numeric ("" & IFERROR(--v, ""))

However, this is not quite perfect.  For example "9.876543621" fulfils those conditions, as do "98,765,432" and "9E+8765432".  If you want to exclude those cases, then you can change the TEXTSPLIT, like so:
TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", "X"), ".", "X"), "E", "X"), " ")

